# Return with Macro C programming

Tags: c, macros, return

This code is always returning -1 even when the fopen() function has executed successfully. Is there something I am ignoring.

```
void nullCheck(FILE* checkVar)  {
    if(checkVar==NULL)  {
        #define _NULL_ERROR
      }
    }

int readFile(char* _name, char* storeArray) {
FILE* fp;
fp=fopen(_name,READ_ONLY_MODE);
nullCheck(fp);
#ifndef _NULL_ERROR
    char c=0;
    while((c=getc(fp))!=EOF) {
        *(storeArray+i)=c;
        i+=1;
    }
#endif
#ifdef _NULL_ERROR
    #undef _NULL_ERROR
    return -1;
#endif
return 1;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: 4 answers in about five mins - Fantastic!

Comment: Well you all are right, I forgot my basics! :) Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what your code looks like to the compiler, after the preprocessor runs:

```
void nullCheck(FILE* checkVar)  {
    if(checkVar==NULL)  {
      }
    }

int readFile(char* _name, char* storeArray) {
FILE* fp;
fp=fopen(_name,READ_ONLY_MODE);
nullCheck(fp);
    return -1;
return 1;
}
```

As has been stated above, the preprocessor deals with macros before the compiler runs.

Comment: In one sense all are right but you have taken the effort to show the code.  :)

Answer (score 5):

Oy va voy! Macros are defined and undefined when your code is compiled, *not* when it runs! They are not affected by control flow statements like "if" and "then" -- they are all processed before compilation of those statements even begins!

Answer (score 3):

You need to re-read the documentation on the C Preprocessor.  The `#define _NULL_ERROR` doesn't get executed when nullCheck is called, it gets interpeted when the preprocessor processes the file before it is compiled.  So you are always setting `_NULL_ERROR` and so you will always return -1.

Answer (score 2):

`#define` is a preprocessor command, which means it's not calculated / processed in the function `nullCheck()` but before the compiling of the code. so `_NULL_ERROR` is always defined and therefore the condition

```
#ifdef _NULL_ERROR
    #undef _NULL_ERROR
    return -1;
#endif
```

will always cause the pre-compiler to add the `return -1;` to your code.

Answer (score 1):

`#define`, `#ifdef`,  and friends don't work like you think they do. They're [preprocessor directives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) that affect your code even before the compiler sees it.  Get your compiler to show you the preprocessed source before it compiles (`-E` or `-save_temps` in gcc and clang) and you'll immediately see what's going on.